# Caputure the keystroke events of remote machine and display them on local machine

Tags: linux, ssh

I have two linux let say A and B systems connected via SSH. On machine A I have a QR scanner connected to it. I want to scan the QR code on machine A redirect it to a file and then display the decoded sting on machine B. For this purpose what I am trying to do is, I do ssh from the local B machine which runs a script to redirect the stdin to a file to capture the decoded strings. It just invoke a script on remote machine which redirect stdin `timeout 5 cat > qrCode.txt`.

The real problem is when invoke the scripts locally on my machine A it works fine, but when I try to do the same from B machine on A using SSH, I get the file `qrCode.txt` on remote machine B but it's empty. Does not contain anything.

So how can I redirect the stdin of remote machine to a file and then read from that file to display the decoded string on local machine. 
I guess the terminal is missing, because the Qr scanner flush out everything to terminal but when i do ssh, there is no access to terminal so it doesn't capture the keystrokes.
Is there anyway to achieve this?

Here is the ssh command on system B

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Going to invoke remotes script"
sshpass -p <password> ssh user@192.168.2.10 -q -tt "/home/user/scanQr.sh"
```

used -tt parameter  to avoid the warning `pseudo terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal`
and this is the script on remote machine A

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/user
cat > code.txt
```

Comment: Please show the exact `ssh` command you are running, and also any errors you might see.

Comment: @merlin2011 if I invoke the script locally on machine A, I get the decoded Qrcode in the file code.txt but when I try to do this using remote system code.txt file gets created on machine A but its empty nothing gets stored in it.

Comment: Is the goal to get `code.txt` on machine A or machine B?

Comment: The goal is to store the decoded string in `code.txt` on machine A which is scanned by Qr scanner attached on machine A. by operating remotely from system B

Comment: Using your `ssh` command, the `cat` command on machine A reads `stdin` from Machine B over ssh, *not* from the QR code scanner, which I assume is pretending to be a keyboard. Rather than using `cat` with no argument, I suspect you will need to `cat` a special device that refers to the actual QR scanner device.

Comment: **Never** write passwords into command line arguments. On Unix command line arguments are public. `ps -ef`

Comment: Yes QR code scanner pretends to be a keyboard and i am sure cat will read from both keyboard and Qr code scanner because both flush data on stdin

Comment: @merlin2011 it comes up as a /dev/hidraw device. Cat on this device dosen't works well

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what happens when you `ssh` and invoke a script directly. If you do this, the remote `cat` doesn't see the remote `stdin` only the local `stdin`.

Comment: Oky, I got you point. and this is the same thing which I want. Is there any way so that I can open a terminal on remote device using ssh? So that the `cat` command will see remote `stdin`

Comment: I would try the answers to [this question](https://superuser.com/q/562434/109158) and comment back here if it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: @merlin2011, thanks for the help, yes it works but doesn't displays the string in a proper way. There are alot of XXX in between the actual string

Comment: And the result get worse if I change this line according to my req.
`keys = "X^1234567890XXXXQWERTYUIOPXXXXASDFGHJKLXXXXXZXCVBNMXXXXX=&XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"`
instead of XXXX I added all the special characters. And I got strange output. I am sure that I have to change something in this line but Is there any prescribed way to place the keys in `keys`

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. This is new territory AFAIK. Please update your question with your current scripts and I'll take a look.